# How can I pass multiple values in a single prop in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

Is there any way where I can pass in multiple values in a single prop?

Right now how it works is I have one component and it takes in lots of values like this:

```
<div>
  <MyComponent
    valueA={100}
    valueB={90}
    valueC={80}
    valueD={70}
    valueE={60}
  />
</div>
```

Here for example A and B are related and I want to pass them together like

```
<div>
  <MyComponent
    valueAB={100, 90}
    valueC={80}
    valueD={70}
    valueE={60}
  />
</div>
```

It probably needs to be in a single object like this: `valueAB={{100, 90}}` but I have no idea.

How can I do this and extract both of the values on the other side?

Comment: Just pass an array or object as a prop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass an array or an object:

```
// e.g
<MyComponent
    valueAB={[100, 90]}
    valueC={{ a: 100, b: 90}} />
```

And in MyComponent you will get valueAB prop
as array, hence you can do something like:

```
props.valueAB[0] // 100
```

Or for objet : `props.valueC.a` is also 100 .

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do add them as a one object as you did {{100, 90}} or one array {[100,90]}

and you can easily extract them from the array like this:

```
let myCompValueABFirst = props.valueAB[0];
let myCompValueABSecond = props.valueAB[1];
```